# a question about omnet++ wireless node's source code

Tags: omnet++

I want to see the source code for sending data packets wirelessly,but I try a lot ,such as refer to tutorials ,but I still can not find it.Who can help me that? very thanks!!

Comment: Welcome at SO! Wireless node consists of many elements (modules) that reflects a real node. Could you precise which aspect of sending a packet are you interested in?

Comment: Thank you for your reply!This is an example from the tutorials.Its location is inet ->tutorials -> wireless -> wirelessA. In its inner layer it has appLayer,transportLayer,networkLayer,and linkLayer. I am interested in the linkLayers "wlan"module.In the "wlan" it has mac and radio .The radio module send the packets wirelessly, and the thing that bothers me now is I can not find the source code to define  how it send packets wirelessly...It seems that there is also a sending range issue involved. I am new to this software ,and also new to SO...I will be very grateful if you could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also new to the OMNET++ and inet. I have exactly same problem as yours. When I search the "wlan" node, I found it was used as submodules in /inet/node/base/LinkLayerNodeBase.ned. The type of "wlan" in default is [image: Ieee80211Interface], which source code is under "/inet/linklayer/ieee80211/ieee80211Interface.ned". I suppose we are using same tutorial, then the omnetpp.ini has claimed that the "wlan" type is AckingWirelessInterface in this sentence
`*.host*.wlan[0].typename = "AckingWirelessInterface"`. And this AckingWirelessInterface is actually another compound module "/inet/linklayer/acking/AckingWirelessInterface" that implement "IWirelessInterface". To find how it handle the packages, you should go to his **submodules**:[image: submodules]. More specifically, you can check "**inet/linklayer/acking/AckingMac.cc**" and "**inet/physicallayer/unitdisk/UnitDiskRadio.cc**" to find  module and  module.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, I have solved this problem, but your reply gave me a new way to solve the problem!

Answer (score 1):

First of all I suggest doing the basic tutorial for OMNeT++ available in [TicToc Tutorial](https://docs.omnetpp.org/tutorials/tictoc/).

The NED definitions as well as C++ source files of link layer are in `src/inet/linklayer`, for example `src/inet/linklayer/ieee80211`. Moreover, take a look at [INET User's Guide](https://inet.omnetpp.org/docs/users-guide/ch-80211.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help ! I will check it out now.